# Adding a password parameter in C Sharp to a flash (flv) client?

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript

Assuming I already know the password. Is there anyway I can add a password parameter in C Sharp to communicate with actionscript client that is asking for a password. I want to code the password in C Sharp so it will automatically put the password in when I log into the client.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how Flash is built, this is (AFAIK) not possible when you're using Flash Player or Flash Lite. HOWEVER, you can accomplish something like this with Adobe AIR, which is used for desktop and mobile applications, using the Flash platform. In order for the following approach, you'd need to publish the AIR application for "Extended Desktop".

In order for this to work, your C Sharp program would need to be command-line. After entering some command-line prompt (such as "READY"), it would need to output the password on a single line.

You would need to start your C Sharp program from the Adobe AIR application, using the NativeProcess ([documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html)).

The following code is a modified version of my own working classes. I make no guarantee regarding errors, as I stripped out several proprietary elements. The first two will need to exist as custom classes in the same package. The folder they are saved in must be at the same level as the .FLA in question, and have the same name as the package name.

CUSTOM EVENT CLASS:

```
package myCustomPackage
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class NativeProcessEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const ON_RECEIVE:String = "onReceive";

        public var customMessage:String = "";

        public function NativeProcessEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false):void
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

NATIVEPROCESS CLASS (this does the communication):

```
package myCustomPackage
{

    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    import myCustomPackage.NativeProcessEvent

    public class nativeProcessChannel extends EventDispatcher
    {
        var startup:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        var file:File = new File();
        var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        private var mEvt:NativeProcessEvent;

        var buffer:Array = [];

        //Constructor    
        public function nativeProcessChannel()
        {
            file = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("mypasswordprogram.exe");
            if(file.exists && NativeProcess.isSupported)
            {
                startup.executable = file;
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, addToBuffer);
                process.start(startup);
            }
            else if(!file.exists)
            {
                trace("ERROR: Cannot find program.");
            }
            else
            {
                trace("ERROR: NativeProcess not supported.");
            }
        }

        //Sends a line of input to the command line.
        public function send(msg:String):void
        {
            process.standardInput.writeUTFBytes(msg + "\n");
        }

        function addToBuffer(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            process.standardOutput.readBytes(bytes, 0, process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
            buffer.push(bytes.toString());
            mEvt = new NativeProcessEvent("onReceive");
            mEvt.customMessage = "NativeProcess message received.";
            dispatchEvent(mEvt);
        }

        //Receives a line of output from the command line
        public function receive():String
        {
            var r:String = "";
            if(buffer.length > 0)
            {
                r = buffer[0]
                buffer.splice(0,1);
            }
            return r;
        }

        //This closes the connection, freeing memory.
        public function close():void
        {
            process.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

IMPLEMENTATION:

```
import myCustomPackage.NativeProcessClass;
import myCustomPackage.NativeProcessEvent;

var myProcess:NativeProcessClass = new NativeProcessClass();
myProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessEvent.ON_RECEIVE, continueGetPassword);

//This function is necessary so you can reuse the NativeProcess channel.
public function reconnect()
{
    myProcess = new NativeProcessClass();
    myProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessEvent.ON_RECEIVE, continueGetPassword);
}

public function getPassword()
{
    myProcess.send("READY");
}

public function continueGetPassword()
{
    var password:String = myProcess.receive();
    //You now have the password from your c-sharp program. Do with it what you like!
    myProcess.close()
    reconnect();
}
```

To my knowledge, there is no other way to connect to another program with Flash, because of its security restrictions. Extended Desktop in Adobe AIR is the only Flash-based platform that doesn't get sandboxed.

Hope this helps (and apologies for any code errors.)